# Using Regex to count word combinations in an text Abstract using VB.net

Tags: sql-server, regex, vb.net

I have a medical dictionary of terms and those terms could be a combination of words such as:
[**Breast Cancer** or **Prostate Cancer**] Or single such as [**Breast** and **Prostate** and **Cancer**] or even [**beta cell tumor of the pancreas**].

I need to count the words in the article abstract that are in the dictionary without counting them twice, so if I count **Breast Cancer** as

1. I should not count **Breast** or **Cancer** individually when they show up together as an additional
2. I'm pulling the words from a MS SQL data base where I added a column that counts the white space between words and sorted by the largest to the smallest and then the word.

What I need to do is when I count the word replace it with a blank or "" so that it is not available to count individually.  I'm not worried about the text in the abstract that can always be updated after.

My VB.net code in a .Net WEB API is:

```vb
While reader.Read '- -pulling words from database

    word = reader("Word").ToString

    Dim regex As Regex

    If word.StartsWith("ER") Then
        regex = New Regex("\s" + word + "\s", RegexOptions.None)
    Else
        regex = New Regex("\s" + word + "\s", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
    End If

    Dim regex As Regex = New Regex("\b(" + word + ")\b", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
    Dim match As Match = regex.Match(abstractText)
    If match.Success Then
        TotalAbstractCount += regex.Matches(abstractText).Count
        abstractCount += 1
        abstractWords.Add(word)
        abstractWordsCount.Add(word + " (" + count.ToString + ")")
        ' new code added to replace word/word string with blank
        Dim regex2 = New Regex(word, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
        abstractText = regex2.Replace(abstractText, " ")

    End If
    match = match.NextMatch()

End While
```

Using this code is there a place that I can update the match to an empty string?  Or do I need to build a loop?

UPDATE: I just added the new code of the regex2 but because it calls a new regex on every word it seems to have slowed down the entire process. The end user is waiting in real time for the results. The entire process I have not timed but it seems that it has gone from 1-1.5 seconds to 3-4.

Also, if there is a faster way to do this in a MS SQL 2016 server I'm open to that.

Comment: post some example files and query results so we can replicate (pastebin?)

Comment: I'm not sure how to answer your question.  I pull the abstract from the xml file https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/?term=30368741&report=xml&format=text  - just the abstract section and then loop 8000+ words from https://www.cancer.gov/publications/dictionaries/cancer-terms that are stored in the database.  Each document is different.  I guess I will accept the less than 3-4 seconds.  Doing what it does it is not a bad process.  I was just wondering if a Regex expert or a SQL guru saw a different answer I would be willing to try it.

Comment: Ooof, pulling those 8000 words out of that dictionary would be quite a bit of effort for someone on SO to go to just so they can test out some code to help you out. Any chance you could provide (via pastebin.com) some example data and all the words you've already extracted?

Answer (score -1):

Here's my (relatively untested) answer.

The algorithm is:

- get the phrases
- get the text
- clean up the text turning everything that is non word character into a space
- loop the phrases, finding `" phrase "` (length 8) and replacing with spaces `"       "` (length 7) - the change in length is the count of occurrences

```vb
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System
Imports System.Linq

Public Module Module1
    Public Sub Main()

        Dim phrases() as String  = { "brEast", "bREast canCer", "caNCer" }

        Dim text as String = "Breast- cAncer is Cancer!! of .the breAst. we need to keep aBREAST of it as it is CANCERous. Breast Cancer is bad cancer"

        Dim cleaner  = new Regex("\W+")

        'remove all non word characters, replacing them with a single space
        Dim cleanText = cleaner.Replace(text, " ")

        'put the text into a stringbuilder for much faster string manipulation
        'add space at the start and end - spaces delimit words for us
        Dim textSb as New StringBuilder(" " & cleanText.ToLower() & " ")

        'something to hold the counts of phrases
        Dim counts = New Dictionary(Of String, Integer)

        'Sort phrases from long to short, prevents "breast" ruining "breast cancer"
        Dim orderedPhrases = phrases.OrderByDescending(Function(p As String) p.Length)

        For Each phrase as String in orderedPhrases

            'capture the old length - we'll need this
            Dim prevLen as Integer = textSb.Length

            'replace all occurrences of the phrase in the text.
            'tack a space onto either end of the phrase to find whole words only

            'because the replacement str is 1 shorter than the find
            'the count of replacements is simply the change in length

            'also we need the replacement string to be spaces
            'because we rely on spaces at the start and end of a
            'find string to delimit a phrase. removing all spaces
            'could break our logic. If we replace with nothing:
            '"type 1 breast cancer cancer is bad" -> "type 1cancer is bad"
            'then we cannot now find " cancer "

            Dim findPhrase = " " & phrase.ToLower() & " "
            Dim replPhrase = new String(" ", findPhrase.Length - 1)
            textSb.Replace(findPhrase, replPhrase)

            'store the count of occurrences of this phrase
            counts(phrase) = prevLen - textSb.Length

        Next phrase

        'let's print our counts as proof it works
        For Each key as String in counts.Keys
            Console.Out.WriteLine(key  & " count is " & counts(key))
            Next key


    End Sub
End Module
```

I don't have a large dataset to try it on but I ran this entire method 100,000 times in 2.5 seconds

https://dotnetfiddle.net/xxlpde

Note: if you're doing this on a lot of texts (e.g as a loop of a collection of texts), you could pre-sort the phrases:

```
Dim orderedPhrases = phrases.OrderByDescending(Function(p As String) p.Length).Select(Function(p as String) " " & s.ToLower() & " ").ToArray()
```

Naturally, then `findPhrase` just becomes `phrase` because we already added spaces to it and ToLower()ed it

Comment: Thank you-- I will work with it and let you know.  I was not the one who down voted.  My first question is you are building a phrases from the text that I have in a database and looping using a datareader - do you think that if I converted the recordset into a comma separated string that would be faster that the datareader?

Comment: Note, I fixed a typo in the regex, make sure you use `\W+`. It wouldn't really matter whether it's an array of phrases or DB results; you can do an `SELECT LCASE(phrase) FROM phrases ORDER BY LEN(phrase) DESC` in your sql just like I've done a lowercase/orderby descending length in the client side here. The key is to do the long replacements first. If you're going to be running this on multiple texts then very definitely download all the phrases first and reuse them, don't repeatedly download them from the db

Comment: If your phrases seldom change also consider downloading them into the server memory and using them from there. You can do a simple cache system by having eg a Module with a Shared array of phrase strings and a DateTime of when they were last downloaded. If more than X minutes have passed since they were downloaded, download them into the shared string array again